# Issues when importing Power BI modell to Azure Analysis Service

Tags: powerbi, azure-analysis-services

hope anyone can help me.
I tried now several times to import my first Power BI model into AZURE Analysis Services. I went through the steps as described by the AZURE team. After I've chosen the right server and the model as PBIX file from my local drive and clicked on import, the following happens:
1. It is running for several minutes.
2. After several minutes it stops without any message or anything similar. The model is afterwards not in AZURE Analysis service.

I tried it now 4 times without any success.

Has anyone made the same experiences? Does anyone know a solution for that?

thanks and br

Christoph

Answer (score 0):

There is a fairly short time-out on the import option for Azure Analysis Services.  If it is a large model, I typically:

1. Export model as a template (pbit)
2. Open PBIT, and select edit instead of load.
3. Save new pbix without applying changes or refreshing data.

This new pbix should be small enough to import as long as there aren't any other issues with the dataset.